# how i center div elements horizontally in css?

Tags: html, center, css

How i can center div elements horizontally, so when i change the width of the browser, the last div go down with css?

So:

```
---||||-||||-||||---

--------||||--------
```

When i write:

```
<div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;">
  <div style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;">
    <div style="width:315px; height:340px; float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Text</div>
    <div style="width:315px; height:340px; float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Text</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then after a element go down, all div elements go to the left side.

Comment: Do you have a specific width in mind?

Comment: Only divs have a specific width

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using `display: inline-block` on the elements and then using `text-align: center` on the container to handle the centering you want:

I cleaned up your HTML but here is the basic HTML formatting with a `container` class and multiple (as many as you want) `block` class DIVs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS modifies the display settings of the blocks and the text-alignment of the container:

```
div.block { 
  display: inline-block; /* this changes the elements to behave more like inline elements (think <span>s) */
  width: 315px; 
  margin: 10px 0; 
  height: 340px; 
}
div.container { 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;  /* this is the magic that centers the elements */
}
```

I put together a small demo that should help demonstrate this method:  **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/5ys369yt/)**

**Be Aware:** a small 'quirk' exists with the `display: inline-block` CSS. it causes a small amount of space to occur between the elements. This can be removed multiple ways, my preferred methods being either using comments or wrapping the closing tags of the DIVs. (the issue is caused by the return/spaces between the elements in the HTML):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Text</div><!--
    --><div class="block">Text</div><!--
    --><div class="block">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Text</div
    ><div class="block">Text</div
    ><div class="block">Text</div>
</div>
```

*[reference for the quirk behavior](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)*

Comment: Concering the "small quirk" on inline-block elements, just some feedback here. I prefer to address this issue of extra spacing by setting the font-size of the parent element of the inline-block elements, to zero. Then, target the elements and reset the font size *within* them back to what I want it to be. No additional HTML markup/comments required, and allows your HTML markup to continue to be well formatted.

Comment: So, in reference to your html markup: .container{font-size:0}.block{font-size:16px}  (or whatever you need it to be). Working example of a revised copy of your JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ys369yt/8/

Comment: Oke, thats good. But what i should do, when the elements don't have all the same amount of lines? -> http://jsfiddle.net/5ys369yt/11/

Comment: @Meogi, the `font-size: 0` technique has issues on andorid as noted in my [reference link to CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). It would be my preferred 'hack' solution if not for the android issues.

Comment: @JRulle Indeed it does, I can see a thin line between each block on Android Chrome. Thank you for pointing this out as I have to support this browser at work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a container `<div>` that is 100% of a given area. Then set each `<div>`'s width inside the container to be a % and `float: left;`. They'll stack next to each other until they do not fit and will break to the next line.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.three {
  width: 33%;
  min-width: 225px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="three">
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="three">
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="three">
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Run the snippet.

Comment: This wont work on smaller viewports. Try manually reducing the size of your browser window, the divs do not resize. Just a heads up

Comment: Yeah I realized that and added a minimum width so it will.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But by you code is the same problem, the elements go to the left side, but that should be in the middle

Comment: Whoops I misunderstood your question then! JRulle's answer is the one you're looking for, then.

Answer (score -1):

You could use media queries to write different css code for different sizes:

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)